# Mongoose aggregation query skipping getters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im have the following mongoose schema

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
 subtotal: {type: Number, required: true, default: 0},
 owner: { type : Number, required : true, index: true},
 products: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}],
}, {
 timestamps: true
});


schema.path('subtotal').set(function(p){
  return p * 100;
});

schema.path('subtotal').get(function(p){
  return parseFloat((p/100).toFixed(2));
});

schema.set('toJSON', {getters: true, setters:true});
schema.set('toObject', {getters: true, setters:true});
```

Running a simple find query returns the subtotal value as expected (e.g. 11.99).

When I run an aggregation query the subtotal value is not divided by 100 as I expect it to be.

```
Order.aggregate([
  { $match: { $and: [
    {status: 'COMPLETE'},
    {premises: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(premisesId)},
    {createdAt:{
      $gte: startOfToday,
      $lt: endOfToday
    }}
  ]}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {hour: {$hour: "$createdAt"}},
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      sales: { $sum: '$subtotal'}
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id.hour": 1
    }
  }
]).exec(function(err, orders){
  //do something
})
```

Is this expected behaviour of aggregation?

Is there a way that I can force the aggregation query to fire the getters.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, that is the expected behavior.

Longer answer requires referencing mongoose's documentation for [`Model.aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate):

> Arguments are not cast to the model's schema because $project operators allow redefining the "shape" of the documents at any stage of the pipeline, which may leave documents in an incompatible format.

Essentially this means the magic of anything mongoose allows via using a schema is not applied when using aggregates (including getters). You will need to include that transform in the pipeline.